# How to make an F# JSON type provider sample available for test project?

Tags: json, f#, type-providers, f#-data

I am using an F# JSON type provider to create a type from a reference JSON document. The reference document "ReferenceItem.json" is part of the F# library. In addition I have a unit test project which tests the library. I am struggling with making the reference document available for the test project without duplicating it.

No matter how I mark "ReferenceItem.json" in Visual Studio (Content, None, Copy to Output etc.) my test project fails to compile because the statement JsonProvider<"ReferenceItem.json"> expects "Reference.json" to be present in the project source folder at compilation time. Including it as a linked item from the library project doesn't help: it's not copied at compile time to the test source folder. So I need to make a duplicate copy of the file in the test project.

I noticed that in F# projects I can mark files as "DesignData" or "DesignDataWithDesignTimeCreatableTypes", but I wasn't able to figure out how I can use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky problem - when F# compiler references the library, it will invoke the type provider and so the type provider needs to be able to access the sample.

The easiest solution is to just always copy the sample `json` file so that it is in the folder from where the application is starting. This is obviously sub-optimal, and so we have another way of handling this using resources.

See the "Using JSON provider in a library" section [of the documentation](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html). The idea is that you can embed the sample document as a resource in the library and specify the resource name as an additional parameter:

```
type WB = JsonProvider<"../data/WorldBank.json", 
                       EmbeddedResource="MyLib, worldbank.json">
```

This will then load the resource when using the library (but it still needs the file name in the original compilation mode). This is still somewhat experimental, so please open an issue on GitHub if you cannot get it to work!

Comment: Thanks Tomas! I'll check EmbeddedResource option.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't even hoping for this to be that easy :-).